# How to set an item in CListCtrl as selected?

Tags: c++, winapi, selection, clistctrl

ClistCtrl is set to single selection & single column in report view with no header.

I have tried `SetItemState(0,LVIS_SELECTED,LVIF_STATE)` and
 `SetSelectionMark(int index)` but these don't work.

Answer (score 13):

you also need to call SetSelectionMark after updating the item states.

```
SetItemState(prev_item, ~LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
SetItemState(new_selected_item, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
SetSelectionMark(new_selected_item);
```

Answer (score 6):

I think there is an undocumented feature of the [`SetItemState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t97k8h9(v=vs.120).aspx) function where you can pass `-1` as its `nItem` argument to make the function act on ***all*** items.

So, if you only want to select ***only one***, I can suggest:

```
    SetItemState(-1, 0, LVIS_SELECTED);
    SetItemState(index, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

*(after seeing http://www.verycomputer.com/417_11fcb075491b88c9_1.htm#p3 )*

The [`SetItemState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t97k8h9(v=vs.120).aspx) function sends the [`LVM_SETITEMSTATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761196(v=vs.130).aspx) message, and the nItem=-1 feature is documented on the [message's reference documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761196(v=vs.130).aspx) as its `wParam` argument.

Comment: Thanks, there's more info in the [macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775102(v=vs.85).aspx) as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use SetItemState(0, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED) to highlight, and 
SetItemState(0, ~LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED) to unhighlight.

Answer (score 4):

Just Set **Properties->Appearance->Always Show Selection** to **TRUE**

Comment: This solved it for me, though not through the GUI. If you are creating your list view control programmatically, the style to be set is `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS`.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the index of the item fo be selected is *w_nCurIdx*, Use the following code

```
m_pSPSMapList.SendMessage(LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
m_pSPSMapList.SetItemState(w_nCurIdx, LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED, LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wont set selected item in OnInitialDialog you mast use this code:

```
m_pSPSMapList->EnsureVisible(nItem, FALSE);
m_pSPSMapList->SetFocus();
m_pSPSMapList->SetItemState(nItem, LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED, 
                                   LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED);

return FALSE; // OnInitialDialog necessarily must return false
```